# Update a document with ReactiveMongo using a condition based on the data inside the document and get the updated doc at the end

Tags: mongodb, scala, reactivemongo

I have a mongodb collection of tasks with documents looks like:

```
id: objId
retries: Int
status: String
lockedUntill: ISO time
```

Retries can be Integers from 1 to 10
statuses can be: `READY`, `AWAIT`, `FAILED`, `DONE`, etc..

I'm using scala with ReactiveMongo and I want to search for 1 doc at a time in status `READY`
and change its lockedUntil based on the number of retries and return the new document.

For example:
if:

- the doc is not locked(task.lockedUntil: {$lt: `now`}),
- the doc status is ready(task.status: `READY`)
  and than some switch that is based on the Int in the retries I will set the locked until.
  for example `{$eq: {$task.retries: 2}}` than `config.secondLockedUntill`

This is the query that is working directly to the db.

```
db.tasks.findOneAndUpdate({ "_id": ObjectId("bla") }, [{
    $set: {
        "task.lockedUntil": { 
            $switch: {
                branches: [
                    { case: { $eq: ["$task.retries", 1] }, then: "" },
                    { case: { $eq: ["$task.retries", 2] }, then: "READY2" },
                    { case: { $eq: ["$task.retries", 3] }, then: "READY3" },
                    { case: { $eq: ["$task.retries", 4] }, then: "READY4" },
                
                ],
            default: "default value"
            }
        }
    }
}])
```

Now I'm tring to convert that to scala and ReactiveMongo code and getting a lot of issues.

Sometimes with js parsing and sometimes with ReactiveMongo operators not supporting aggregation pipline.

`collection.findAndUpdate` is not supporting aggregation pipeline and update
`update.one` is not returning the document.

Any ideas? Is it possibe or I have to split it to multiple operations?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `collection.aggregationUpdateModifier(updateAggPipeline, fetchNewBool, upsertBool)` in combination with `collection.findAndModify(selector, updateModifier)`